# Stop page refreshing when Country is selected from Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a form where the user enters in details like name, address etc. And I am using a DropDownList for the Countries. When a country is selected, it populates the counties dropdownlist. The problem is using `AutoPostBack="true"` is causing the page to refresh. But without it the counties dropdownlist won't populate.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_Click" ID="ddlCountry"  Width="80px"></asp:DropDownList>
```

code for function:

```
protected void ddlCountry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.Parse(ddlCountry.SelectedValue) > 0)
        {
            LoadCounties(int.Parse(ddlCountry.SelectedValue));
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayMsg("Please select a valid country!");
        }

    }
```

Is there a way to stop the whole page refreshing, but still populate the counties after a country is selected?

Comment: Populate the other dropdown at client side using jQuery. Check this - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-Cascading-DropDownList-using-jQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: @RahulSingh could you show some code on how to do that?

Comment: Recent example of cascading drop down lists using ajax and .net http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-Cascading-DropDown-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: The easiest way to do this in asp.net is use updatepanel but its not really efficient because it still goes through the page life cycle so look into using jquery ajax and also you might need to know WebMethod attribute for your c# function

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery ajax or this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataSource ID="businessgroup" DataTextField="BusinessGroupName" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_2" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>        
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```